# select a checkbox in one page automatically select in another page using php,javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

i designed 2 html pages,here i find some same code for check boxes in 2 pages .i want this one ,when i select the checkbox in first page ,then automatically select the same checkbox in the 2nd page .how can i do this one?

my code for chk box in 2 pages

Would you like to  make this available for others to copy ?

Yes
No

Comment: pass the value of the checkbox to the next page by form submit or thru javascript page load and get it where required. Check the value and make it **checked=true or false** depending on the value.

Comment: i dont know,how can i do this one?

Comment: check box will be in a form. While submitting the form, get the value of the check box in php code. Now do what ever you want (like saving the values or interpreting it). Set the value to session if you wish and get it on the next html page. Or while redirecting to the next page pass the value as GET param to the next page with URL. Get the $_GET param and check your condition.

Comment: $_SESSION['whatever-var-u-want'] = your check box value. thats it.

Comment: here,checkbox is selected by user

Answer (score 1):

Let this be your html form.

```
<form action="your/action" method="POST" name="form">
      <input type="checkbox" name="postCheckBox" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

In /your/action.php page

```
$_SESSION['postCheckBox'] = isset($_POST["postCheckBox"]) ? $_POST["postCheckBox"] : null;
```

In your next html page:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="somename" <?php echo isset($_SESSION['postCheckBox']) && $_SESSION['postCheckBox'] == 1 ? 'checked="true": ""' ?>value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do this is to simply add a value in your session and read it on the other page.

Comment: can u tell the example how can i add to this in session?

Answer (score 0):

```
Checkbox will select automatically perticular checkboxes from selected price list of home page.

    $("input[name=categories]").each( function (index) {    
        iterations = $.cookie('total_iterations');

        var orgval = $(this).val();
        for (var i = 1; i <= iterations; i++) {
            var chkval =$.cookie("plan_item_cookie_cb_"+i);
            if(chkval.trimRight() == orgval )
            {
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
            }
       };
    });

    $('#plan_section_id_1').click(function(){
        var cookies = $.cookie();
        for(var cookie in cookies) {
           $.removeCookie(cookie);
        }

        var count=0;
        //alert('outside');
        $('#plan_section_id_1').find('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
            //alert('in');
            its = $('#plan_section_id_1 .total_iterations').val();
            if ($(this).val().length) {
            //if ($.trim($(this).val()).length) {
                count++;
                $.cookie('plan_item_cookie_cb_'+count,decodeURI($(this).val()),60);
                //$.cookie('section-id','plan_section_id_1');
                $.cookie('total_iterations',its);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#plan_section_id_2').click(function(){
        var cookies = $.cookie();
        for(var cookie in cookies) {
           $.removeCookie(cookie);
        }

        var count=0;
        $('#plan_section_id_2').find('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
            its = $('#plan_section_id_2 .total_iterations').val();
            if ($(this).val().length) {
            //if ($.trim($(this).val()).length) {
                count++;
                $.cookie('plan_item_cookie_cb_'+count,decodeURI($(this).val()),60); 
                $.cookie('total_iterations',its);
            }
        });

    });

    $('#plan_section_id_3').click(function(){
        var cookies = $.cookie();
        for(var cookie in cookies) {
           $.removeCookie(cookie);
        }
        var count=0;
        $('#plan_section_id_3').find('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
            its = $('#plan_section_id_3 .total_iterations').val();
            if ($(this).val().length) {
            //if ($.trim($(this).val()).length) {
                count++;
                $.cookie('plan_item_cookie_cb_'+count,decodeURI($(this).val()),60);
                $.cookie('total_iterations',its);
            }
        });

    });
```